# R markdown: how to insert space between images

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to add two images side by side in R markdown, but with some space between them.
How can I adjust the space between the images? Thank you!

```
![](/Users/filename/black.png){width=50%} 
![](/Users/filename/gray.png){width=50%}
```

[image]

Comment: whats the output format?!

Comment: @shafee output format should be html!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One option** could be using `ggdraw() + draw_image` from `{cowplot}`

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```


```{r side_by_side, fig.align='center'}

library(cowplot)

ggdraw() + 
  draw_image("test_logo.png", width = 0.4) + 
  draw_image("test_animal.jpg", width = 0.4, x = 0.5)

```
````

Which looks like

[image: side_by_side]

**Another option** could be making white border for the images using `image_border` from the `{magick}` package so that even if there is no actual space between them, white border will look like a space.

````
```{r another_option, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}

library(magick)

img1 <- image_read("test_logo.png")
bordered_img1 <- image_border(img1, "white", "20x20")

img2 <- image_read("test_animal.jpg")
bordered_img2 <- image_border(img2, "white", "20x20")

image_write(bordered_img1, "img1.png")
image_write(bordered_img2, "img2.jpg")

```

```{r side_img, out.width="50%"}
knitr::include_graphics(c("img1.png", "img2.jpg"))
```
````

Which looks like,

[image: side_by_side]