# Bookdown - Add space between side by side figures using knitr::include_graphics

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, bookdown

The recomended way to include existing images in bookdown is using `knitr::include_graphics`.

For example, to put two images side by side code will be something like:

````
```{r myfigure fig.show='hold', fig.align='center', out.width='50%', fig.cap = ""}
fig1_path <- paste0(fig_path,"image1.png")
fig2_path <- paste0(fig_path,"image2.png")

knitr::include_graphics(c(fig1_path, fig2_path))
```
````

However, this produces html and latex where the images are very close each other. It would be desirable to add some space/padding/margin between to look better.

For the html case, this is easy to fix because we can add some external css to control the space. However, for the latex output i don't have any decent solution yet.

Im thinking a portable workaround could be to add an extra empty image between or add lateral space to both images, but i prefer to hear better suggestions.

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-placement.html

Comment: If that's an option, consider to switch to Quarto, which would [make this easy.](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/figures.html#complex-layouts)

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241475/10858321) which should work for both HTML and latex output format.